# Publication title with "the" or without

Tags: grammar, articles, titles

I'm currently struggling which of the following two versions (I anononymized them) is the correct grammatical form for the title of a publication:

> Evaluating Safety, Cleverness and Fastness of Masking Systems
>
> Evaluating **the** Safety, Cleverness and Fastness of Masking Systems

We are currently using the first version. Is it missing "**the**"?

Comment: I think our case is different since the examples in the other thread either contain a colon or a dash. In our case, we don't have those. Does it make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Bear in mind that titles are often not complete sentences (yours isn't, for example), and they don't necessarily adhere to standard principles of grammar anyway.

Comment: It is common to drop articles in titles. You see this a lot in newspaper headlines.

Comment: Use the one that you (and whoever is "we") think will be easier to read.  If I were the author, I'd put in "the".